# Understanding the process for finding partial derivatives of a variable in convoluted implicit functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to clear up a consistent source of confusion for myself when finding the partial derivatives of an implicitly defined function. I think I have gotten the hang of the process but I often get confused because I don't think I actually know what I'm actually *doing* and *why*.

As an example: Let *u* be defined as a function of $x,y$ by means of the equation 
$$
u=F(x+u,yu)
$$
Find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ in terms of the partials of $F$.

The method seems to be "ok, I can define some function $g(x,y)=u$ and then I can rewrite the arguments of $F$ in a way that doesn't lead to an equation where all of the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$'s cancel (this step in particular is confusing, why do they cancel sometimes?) as $F(u_1(x,y),u_2(x,y))$ and then we get
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=D_1F\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+D_2F\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}\\
=D_1F(1+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x})+D_2Fy\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\\
=D_1F(1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})+D_2Fy\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
$$
Which we can now solve for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ as normal.

Any explanation for why the steps are necessary or any theoretical underpinnings I am missing would be helpful. If this is really just best understood as a process, that's ok too I just want to know. I have really had trouble finding good explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let $c(x,y) = \langle c^1=x+u,c^2=yu\rangle$ then using Chain Rule you have:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (F \circ c) = \nabla F\Bigr|_{c(x,y)} \cdot \left\langle \frac{\partial c^1}{\partial x} \Bigr|_{(x,y)}, \frac{\partial c^2}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{(x,y)} \right\rangle = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^1}\Bigr|_{c(x,y)}\frac{\partial c^1}{\partial x^1} \Bigr|_{(x,y)} +\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^2}\Bigr|_{c(x,y)}\frac{\partial c^2}{\partial x^1} \Bigr|_{(x,y)}$$

Edit: Let $f(x,y)$ be differentiable and $c(x,y) = \langle c^1,c^2 \rangle$ be differentiable as well. Suppose also that $f \circ c$ is defined (then it is differentiable). Let $ f\circ c$ be differentiable at $(a,b)$ then:

$$\frac{\partial (f \circ c)}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{(a,b)} = \frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=a} (f \circ c)(t,b) = \nabla f\Bigr|_{c(a,b)} \cdot \left\langle\frac{\partial c^1}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{(a,b)},\frac{\partial c^2}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{(a,b)}\right\rangle$$

Comment: Right so I did this. Do you have any answers to my questions?

Comment: You were confused on how the implicit differentiation works. If you take some time to really see the difference in our work, you'll see where I answer your questions. I showed you that you are really treating $u$ as a composition of $F$ with some curve. Then if you want to take a partial, you are differentiating with respect to one variable and so you are really looking at a composition which is dependent on one variable i.e you know how to do this, it's chain rule. My answer differs more because I show you that there is a distinction between $x^1,x$ and $x^2,y$.

Comment: Ah. The words composing with a curve I think is helpful. I will keep thinking

Comment: Yeah, just think about the regular chain rule for curves: $$ \frac{d}{dt} (f \circ c) = \nabla f\Bigr|_{c(0)} \cdot c'(0)$$. Here $c$ is a function of more than one variable, but when taking a partial, you can think of the composition as a function of one variable. I think this vague sentence I am saying is where your question is, I'll edit.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an abuse of coordinates in these problems? As in is u being used as a coordinate as well a variable? I'm not sure if this makes sense

Comment: I edited and yes there is a great abuse of notation. If you are point to let $p = (x,y)$ be a point then you need to choose different coordinate functions for $\mathbb{R}^2$ say $x^1,x^2$. If not, we say $p = (x_0,y_0)$ and let $x,y$ be the standard coordinate functions.

Comment: this was quite helpful, thank you